# Getting AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split' while converting the .log file formate to .json format

Tags: python, json, logging

Hello guys i have a log file  **This log information i have created by python program but want to print this log file into .json file**

```
2018-12-04 11:45:41,820 - DATA-MANUFACTURING - INFO - Uploading the file
2018-12-04 11:45:41,852 - DATA-MANUFACTURING - DEBUG - recordCount - 1000
2018-12-04 11:45:41,853 - DATA-MANUFACTURING - DEBUG - fromYear - 1970
2018-12-04 11:45:41,853 - DATA-MANUFACTURING - DEBUG - toYear - 1974
2018-12-04 11:45:41,854 - DATA-MANUFACTURING - DEBUG - FileName - <FileStorage: 'Data_Large1.csv' ('application/vnd.ms-excel')>
2018-12-04 11:45:41,899 - DATA-MANUFACTURING - DEBUG - File saved to destination folder
2018-12-04 11:45:41,900 - DATA-MANUFACTURING - INFO - Uploading file is done
2018-12-04 11:45:41,902 - werkzeug - INFO - 127.0.0.1 - - [04/Dec/2018 11:45:41] "POST /UploadFile HTTP/1.1" 302 -
2018-12-04 11:45:41,912 - DATA-MANUFACTURING - INFO - Data manufacturing process started
2018-12-04 11:45:41,913 - DATA-MANUFACTURING - DEBUG - Year Array - [1970, 1971, 1972, 1973, 1974]
2018-12-04 11:45:41,954 - DATA-MANUFACTURING - INFO - Readed the csvfile
2018-12-04 11:45:41,955 - DATA-MANUFACTURING - INFO - Segmentation for the 'recordCount' is started
2018-12-04 11:45:41,955 - DATA-MANUFACTURING - INFO - SegmentValues is appended
2018-12-04 11:45:41,956 - DATA-MANUFACTURING - DEBUG - segmentValues - [1, 2.0, 3, 4, 2, 1, 5, 89, 1, 10, 81, 1]
2018-12-04 11:45:41,957 - DATA-MANUFACTURING - INFO - segmentation for the data is done
2018-12-04 11:45:42,183 - DATA-MANUFACTURING - INFO - Segmentation for the 'recordCount' is started
2018-12-04 11:45:42,184 - DATA-MANUFACTURING - INFO - SegmentValues is appended
2018-12-04 11:45:42,185 - DATA-MANUFACTURING - DEBUG - segmentValues - [1, 1, 9, 108, 31, 1, 35, 1, 1, 1, 2.0, 9]
2018-12-04 11:45:42,186 - DATA-MANUFACTURING - INFO - segmentation for the data is done
2018-12-04 11:45:42,475 - DATA-MANUFACTURING - INFO - Segmentation for the 'recordCount' is started
2018-12-04 11:45:42,476 - DATA-MANUFACTURING - INFO - SegmentValues is appended
2018-12-04 11:45:42,477 - DATA-MANUFACTURING - DEBUG - segmentValues - [1, 1, 8, 1, 5, 1, 112, 2.0, 48, 1, 2, 18]
2018-12-04 11:45:42,477 - DATA-MANUFACTURING - INFO - segmentation for the data is done
```

for this i have written a code which is got online:

```
with open("info.log", "r") as log_file:
    log_string = log_file.read().splitlines()
response_string = log_string.split("Response :")[1].strip()
response_obj = json.loads(response_string)
with open("outfile", "w") as out_file:
    out_file.write(json.dumps(response_obj))
```

but here i'm getting errror like:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Then i tried with other way :

```
with open('data_generation.log', 'r') as logfile, open('output.json', 'w') as jsonfile:
    json_data = re.search(r'(Response:\s*)(.*)(?=\(HttpClientUtil\))', logfile.read(), re.DOTALL)
    if json_data:
        json.dump(json.loads(json_data.group(2)), jsonfile)
```

Here DOTALL is not working i don't know why its not working...**actually i don't know json so much so i'm not getting how to it if anyone know how to do it please help me..Thanks**

Comment: try: `log_file.read().splitlines()`

Comment: @Rafael bro its not working its giving this error "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'" for this line "response_string = log_string.split("Response :")[1].strip()"

Comment: This is caused by your `log_string.split("Response :")..`

Comment: yea but do u have any other way do it how to fixed that can you please tell me @Rafael

Comment: `response_string = log_string.split("Response :")[1].strip()` - test this line with a string that doesn't contain 'Response :'. If the split string isn't found then you can't take the 2nd element of that list, because the list only has one element. You need to handle it in some way first. it's not good practice but you could just do something like `if len(response_obj) > 1:`

Comment: for your second attempt, I don't see any of the groups you're matching in your regex in your example, so we can't really help you with that, although it's probably that the matching groups on the ends are incorrect in some way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to convert the log file to the json,
you can read the the log file line-by-line like

`fo = open("foo.txt", "rw+")`
`linesOfLogs = fo.readlines()`

once you have the lines we can iterate over the linesofLogs and split the string based on 'Response :' and then we can use the all the elements as the keys except the last one. and using the last one as the value for the json
we can do something like :

```
jsonData = {}
for lineOfLog in liesOfLogs:
    listOfStrings = lineOfLog.split('Response :')
    if len(listOfStrings)>1:
        jsonData[listOfStrings[0]] = listOfStrings[1]
```

now we can easily save the jsonData by using the json library of python